# Latex Animate package - Package animate Error: None of the files

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, animate, png

I am trying to make Beamer class with animations inside. This is my current code. It adds simply one frame, with animation made of 75 png frames named "out-0.png" to "out-74.png".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{animate}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Anim1}
\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{wylot/out-}{0}{74}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

First I tried running the code on Overleaf editor, using pdfLaTeX as compiler - the code itself worked, however later I need to add few huge animations, and Overleaf simply times out. I tried downloading project onto my computer, and compile it with pdfLaTeX installed with Miktex (pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6)). This time, compiler shows this error:

```
! Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate)                `wylot/out-0.eps',
(animate)                `wylot/out-0.mps' or
(animate)                `wylot/out-0.ps'
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.

See the animate package documentation for explanation.
```

How can I repair this, why does animate not allow png file here?

Comment: are you sure that you used pdflatex and not latex?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it was the fastest answered question of my life. I indeed used latex, and not pdflatex - I was confused because both commands showed the same "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6)" after running them, but using command pdflatex instead compiled successfully. Thank you.